# Hosting several sites on a server... change default site?

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS instance running Amazon Linux 2.
I'm currently hosting several sites on it using vhosts.conf

my problem is that if the IP address of the server is entered into the browser then the first site i setup on this server is shown.

I'd like to just show a blank page rather than one specific site.

This seems to have become an issue because when one of my hosted clients put their URL into an email in outlook live it shows a thumbnail and excerpt from the site, but it's showing the wrong site!
Apparently outlook live uses Bing to show this information, and i can only think that it's looking up the IP address and being presented with contents from the (incorrect) default website.

Thanks!

Comment: Set the document path to somewhere not default path for all the websites and locate the black page into the default path, i.e. `/var/www/index.html`

Comment: where would i set the document path?

Comment: Sorry, `DocumentRoot` for each virtual hosts.

Comment: i have a document root set for all of the sites i list in vhosts.conf.... how would i define a 'default site' which will show if just the IP and no domain name is entered?

Comment: if the web is not vhosted, usually it opens the index file at /var/www/ but it depends on the OS.

Comment: this isn't really helping me... i have vhosts.conf set up, i'm hosting a few sites, all that is working corectly... i'm just trying to find how to set it up so that the 'default' site (ie if the IP address is entered) will be something i specify... i presume this is something i can define in vhosts, but i'm not sure how...

Comment: Not virtual hosted = Physically hosted = Default.

Comment: i honestly have no idea what you're talking about